# homework probability question involving indicators with geometic variable

Tags: probability

I am solving a question and came across something new to me,

first - the question - 
in a box there are $2$ regular coins, $p=q=0.5$ and $4$ "fake coins" $p=1/4$

define $X = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{fake coin}
\\ 0, & \text{regular coin}
\end{cases}$

and $N$ as the first time we got a success (shifted geometic variable, $E=\frac{1}{P}$)

and I am asked to find $Cov(X,N)$

so - $Cov(X,N)=E(XN)-(EX)(EN)$...
I got to $E(N)=E(E(N|X))=E(2(X+1))$

the last part is what I didnt understood - it does looks like $N|X\sim Geo(\frac{1}{2(X+1)})$ and it turns out fine if we substitute the values - we get p=0.5 or p=0.25

but - is there a trick behind it ? some indicator black magic? or that I just needed to be creative to find that connection?

thanks for your time

Comment: Not too black, because you have written the $p$s in terms of $X$.

Comment: Since all six coins are in the same box, the probabilities you mention on the fake and regular coins, are _conditional_ probabilities, conditioned on the event that we have chosen a fake or a regular coin, isn't that so?

Comment: I understood it, but the solution I saw just wrote E(E(N|X))=E(2(X+1)) - didnt understood why, then did the substitution and saw that it works out. I wanted to know if that is just a creative trick - or that there is some other way other then guessing it